# How to show Laravel voyager sidebar like (Add Post) for custom Bread builder

Tags: laravel, voyager

I'm new in Laravel Voyager. At Voyager admin section I see there is a **sidebar** section on right side for `Post image`, `SEO contents`.

[image: Check attach Image]

But When I create any custom Bread  for example `"Products"`. There is no right sidebar like `Add Page`/`Add Post`.

My question is how can I create a right sidebar section like that?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating overrides for views for default Voyager add-edit blade, read this documentations here :

https://docs.laravelvoyager.com/customization/overriding-files#overriding-bread-views

by default voyager uses bootstrap 3, you can break the form in rows and column as per your choice.

I hope this will help.